# set different color on each listview row

Tags: android, listview

I have seen related answers and I do not know ehich one is the appropriate for me.
I have a listView and each row has a textview. I want given some conditions, each row to get different color.(Imagine that I am getting data from a DB, and given the value I get, i want text set to different color) My code is shown below:

```
public class TrailsConditionScreen extends ListActivity {
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        seeTrails();
    }
 private void seeTrails() {
    String[] help=new String[] {"foo","bar"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.text1,help);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

}
This code so far just prints them on the list.

Now I want when retrieving values from the db, given the value i get set a different color on each row. imagine that my codes retrieves data from a table an I want when reading the first line , given the number set the appropriate color on the first line of the listview. Then go to second lone of the db,set color for the second line of the list and so on.. i have successfully implemented the reading from the db but i do not know how to set color on specific row. In pseudo-code it looks like this.

```
 for i=0 to number of lines in db{
   read_data();
   if key_value=0 then color_of_line(i)=red;
  else color_of_line_i)=green;
}
```

Any help for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must create a custom adapter to handle this instead of using the ArrayAdapter. Extend the ArrayAdapter and override the **getView** method. And inside the **getView** method based on the condition you can change the color of the text on your **textView.setTextColor**.

To write a custom adapter check the [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) here (6. Tutorial: Implementing your own adapter). This example doesn't use the holder pattern but you should.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to extend ArrayAdapter and create your own class.

In the `getView()` method, execute your condition and set the color to be drawn. There are a lot of good tutorials on creating your own adapters. Check, for instance, http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Inorder to achieve this, you will need to use a custom adapter. Since you mentioned, you are getting the data from a database, I am assuming here that you will have information in a cursor adapter. Hence, a good place to start would be to extend cursor adapter.

Within your new custom adapter, you should override getView() method. The view to be used for each item in list view is specified there. Additionally, you can also set the properties of the view there.

Depending on your business logic, you should set the text color in getView.

A tutorial here:
http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a CustomAdapter for the list view

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

and in the funcion

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

you have the position and you can change whatever you want.

If you search google by custom adapter listview you will get some examples

Answer (score -1):

Different Color For different list item ,yes this can be achieved only if items are static only , but for dynamic content it's hard to do ...