# Changing the color of each row in the Expandable listview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Now am working on expandable listview. I followed this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

I want each row and its corresponding children of an Expandable listview to be set in a single color. There will be a main list in the expandable listview that i want each element to be in different color and when I expand I will get its children that should be in the same color as my parent.How can i do this? Can anyone help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some code, so we can see what you've got already and what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

That's relatively easy. You need to create an [`ExpandableListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) and implement the [`getGroupView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getGroupView%28int,%20boolean,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) and [`getChildView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildView%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) methods. There you can set the background color of every groupitem and child item to your liking.

Comment: I modified it like this buddy its entering into debug perspective               public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
   View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
  return convertView;
 }

Comment: Can u tell me how can i call this getChildView in the main activity

Comment: You don't call this yourself, it's called by the ListView when showing child views. You really should go and read some basic tutorial on ExpandableListView first.

Comment: I was trying to use that so that i can get the view and change its color. I dont know how to change the color in getGroupView() and getChildView() that's why asked you in that way

Comment: Thanks for your guidance it made me close to my answer and i got it

Answer (score 0):

you must have separate XMLs for Child and Parents.just set `android:background` with different colors in the layout like this ,also if you want different Text color,use `android:textColor`.This Would work!

Comment: I dont want all parents to be in same color. I want it to be in different color

Comment: Ok.check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838178/set-different-color-on-each-listview-row    if you haven't tried it,can give it a go.. :)

Comment: go through this link..I think that's exactly what you need.  [link](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/)